# Command-line application using Spring context never ends

Tags: java, spring, program-entry-point, freeze

I created mini framework to executing some spring beans from `main()` method rather than deploying and running full-fledged webapp just to launch those beans. It looks like this:

```
public abstract class BaseLauncher {

    private static final String APP_CONTEXT_PATH = "com/project/dev/launchers/launchersApplicationContext.xml";
    static ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(APP_CONTEXT_PATH);

    protected void launch() {
        context.getBean(getClass()).perform();
        //The process never ends so we want to know when we can kill it
        System.out.println("launcher finished");
    }

    @Transactional
    abstract protected void perform();

}
```

And example launcher looks like this:

```
@Component
public class ParamLoaderLauncher extends BaseLauncher {
    @Inject
    ParamLoader paramLoader;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ParamLoaderLauncher().launch();
    }

    @Override
    protected void perform() {
        paramLoader.loadParams();
    }
}
```

It all works great except that when the invoked bean method is finished, application just keep running and we need to kill it manually. I guess it has something to do with using spring app context. Maybe some special spring-related non-deamon thread is launched? If so, is there any way to kill it? Or what other cause of this may be in such simple code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For standalone applications (not running in any container), [shutdownhook needs to be registered](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-shutdown) for clean shutdown of the spring container when application exits.